# BigQuery Dataset name include as column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I know the answer to this is going to be so simple, but I am going to ask anyway. (Beginner to SQL and GBQ)

I have multiple data sets in Bigquery which have the same database schema. I writing a query to pull data and then utilizing the UNION ALL function.

When writing this in SQL Server Manager I can use the @@SERVERNAME to identify the server and GROUP BY. When I use this function in BIGQUERY it comes up with an error/command not recognised.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, and go easy :)

Thanks
A

Answer (score 1):

You can hardcode values that you want:

```
select t.*, 'dataset1' as dataset
from `project.dataset1.table1`
union all
select t.*, 'dataset2' as dataset
from `project.dataset2.table1`;
```